# Should the players know what monster they're fighting according to the rule book?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, gm-techniques

I've read through several rule books and modules, none of which specify whether or not the players should be told what monster they're fighting or if a description (and leave it at that) is enough.

Did I overlook something, or is this truly unspecified?

Comment: I think the linked questions should have what you're looking for here.